# Multiplayer game server client sockets

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, multiplayer

I am creating simple client server communication for multiplayer game. Server should only broadcast message to every other player connected. I wanted to have one separate thread for each player and this is how I did it:

Server:

```
public class Server extends Thread {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName());

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 6066;

    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't start server");
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("LISTENING...");
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("GOT CONNECTION");

                PlayerThread playerThread = new PlayerThread(clientSocket);
                playerThread.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception occured on server");
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Server is down.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Server(SERVER_PORT);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

PlayerThread:

```
public class PlayerThread extends Thread {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PlayerThread.class.getName());

    private static List<PlayerThread> players = new ArrayList<PlayerThread>(4);

    private Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;

    private String playerName;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public PlayerThread(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        try {
            this.socket = socket;
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Couldn't read stream");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                String inputMessage = in.readUTF();
                System.out.println("GOT: " + inputMessage);
                JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(inputMessage);
                String senderName = jsonNode.get("senderName").asText();

                if (!players.contains(this)) {
                    playerName = senderName;
                    players.add(this);
                    players.forEach((p) -> System.out.println(p));
                }

                for (PlayerThread p : players) {
                    p.getOut().writeUTF(inputMessage);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Player disconnected: " + playerName);
                players.remove(this);
                break;
            }
        }

        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Couldn't close stream");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [name=" + playerName + "]";
    }

    public DataInputStream getIn() {
        return in;
    }

    public DataOutputStream getOut() {
        return out;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((playerName == null) ? 0 : playerName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PlayerThread other = (PlayerThread) obj;
        if (playerName == null) {
            if (other.playerName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!playerName.equals(other.playerName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

On the client side I create socket and send JSON:

```
    playerSocket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);
    in = new DataInputStream(playerSocket.getInputStream());
    out = new DataOutputStream(playerSocket.getOutputStream());
    out.writeUTF(JSONConverter.ObjectToJSON(message));
```

The problem is that for every connection, new thread and new socket is created. I could do another Player class and keep them in List but it still means that every connection creates it's own thread.
Messages from player are sent every 100ms so after 1s I will have 10 thread which is obviously wrong. How should I do it?

Comment: Ok I think I found issue myself. Instead of sending message I created Player instance everytime I got message on client side. Constructor of Player connects to the server and this is why every connection has it's own socket. Actually it was separate connection each time